# Inner Join with WHEREs & ANDs

Tags: sql, join

For some reason I'm still having `SMS_ENABLED` returning `1`s and `ACTIVE` returning `0`s. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
SELECT 
    ROLE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, t.CLUB_ID, sms_enabled, active
FROM TFO_USER t    
INNER JOIN CLUB c
    ON c.CLUB_ID = t.CLUB_ID
WHERE 
    t.ROLE_ID=2 OR t.ROLE_ID=3 AND c.SMS_ENABLED=0 AND c.ACTIVE=1;
```

Comment: use brackets if you use OR and AND in the same condition

Comment: `t.ROLE_ID IN(2, 3)` will fix the issue and is less verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your clause with parenthesis:

```
SELECT 
   ROLE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, t.CLUB_ID, sms_enabled, active
FROM
   TFO_USER t
      INNER JOIN CLUB c ON c.CLUB_ID = t.CLUB_ID
WHERE ( t.ROLE_ID=2 OR t.ROLE_ID=3 ) AND 
      c.SMS_ENABLED=0 AND 
      c.ACTIVE=1
```